# Why a compiler ( say javac ) has to know the size of the object?

Tags: object, compiler-construction, runtime, javac, .class-file

I wondered why the size of an object ( class ) has to be known by the compiler. I mean can't it be deferred to the runtime - when the object is really needed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javac *doesn't* know the size of an object. The JVM abstracts away those details.

In native compiled languages like C or C++, the compiler has to know the size of an object when including it inside a larger struct or when allocating it on the stack.* In the case of heap allocations, it is possible to have a dynamically sized object, though this is very dangerous and hard to get right. In C this is traditionally done by ending the struct with an empty array and then allocating extra space.

Rust actually makes a distinction between types with known and unknown size. The later can only be used in limited circumstances. C/C++ has a similar notion with incomplete types, that are basically only usable as opaque pointers.

* Technically C does allow variable sized arrays on the stack.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying JVM determines size of objects right when they're really needed ( at runtime ) and doesn't matter if those objects reside on heap or non-heap area right ? And for the C++ compiler, does it have a chance to determine it at runtime ( for the stack allocations, at least theoretically ) ?

Comment: @zgulser The JVM can do whatever it wants to. In practice, the size of an object is fixed by its class definition (loaded once at runtime) and all objects are heap allocated, unless they can be optimized away. Arrays have special handling.

Comment: Got it. How arrays are handled then?

Comment: IIRC, variable sized arrays on the stack were added to the spec with C99, but it still took some time before you could assume that all compilers actually support it. That might be used as an indicator for the difficulties associated with objects of unknown size on the stack…